# How to change to color of a link with mouse over effect?

Tags: html

I have a link in blue color.

I want to it to be in black color. Then when a person rolls his mouse over it, it should change to black link with the underline.

Comment: a:link
{
color:#000000;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover
{
color:#000000;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
a:visited
{
 color:#000000;
 text-decoration: none;
}


I used this.Thank you jskiles!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you familiar with CSS? You can define effects on anchors like:

```
a:link  { color: #000000; }
a:hover { text-decoration: underline;  }
```

Comment: +1 Good answer, @jskiles1. I hope you don't mind, I've indented your code for you.

Comment: Oops, yea. I'm still new here. Thanks!

Comment: thanks a lot it worked! Why is it that sometimes we can use 
A.(classname):link{etc)?

what does a: here signify?

Comment: The "a" in "a:" is a CSS modifier for an "<a ...>" tag -- a hyperlink.